# Kivy: Trying to continuously "refresh" a screen in Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I am writing a code for a user interface and to put it simply I am trying to refresh a page until an external variable changes. Once this external variable is changed, I want to then move onto the next screen(This value is coming from an arduino).

```
class screenTwo(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(screenTwo, self).__init__(**kwargs)

       self.screenTwoLabel = Label(text="Screen Two")
       self.add_widget(self.screenTwoLabel)

       if(READ_ARDUINO == b'Finished):
           Clock.schedule_once(self.go_screenthree, 2)

       Clock.schedule_interval(self.go_loop, 3)

   def go_loop(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = 'screenTwo'

   def on_enter(self, *args):
       # start the timer for 10 seconds
       self.timer = Clock.schedule_once(self.idle_logout, IDLE_DELAY)

   def on_leave(self, *args):
       self.timer.cancel() # This is where the error comes in
       self.timer = None

   def on_touch_down(self, touch):
       if self.timer is not None:
           self.timer.cancel()

    self.timer = Clock.schedule_once(self.idle_logout, IDLE_DELAY)
    return super(screenTwo, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do but if I run this I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'screenTwo' object has no attribute 'timer'
```

I have some other things in this code such as the on_enter, and on_leave commands for inactivity purposes but was wondering how I could bypass this because logically it seems like it should work. The weird thing is every other screen has the on_enter, on_leave, on_touch_down timers but none give an error and work functionally.

Comment: you are not actually showing us the part of the code that has the error(the actual place you have an error probably looks like `obj.timer` or `self.timer`   and  `self` or `obj` are `screenTwo`  ... and what its telling you is that your class does not have anything called "timer"

Comment: Sorry about that, just edited the code and description slightly.

Answer (score 0):

in your onLeave self.timer may not exist (and even if it exists it might be None, which would not have a `.cancel` method)

```
class screenTwo(Screen):
    timer = None # now timer will exist
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):           
       super(screenTwo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       self.screenTwoLabel = Label(text="Screen Two")
       self.add_widget(self.screenTwoLabel)
       ...
    
    def onLeave(self):
       if(self.timer): # check to make sure it exists...
          self.timer.cancel()
        ...
```